# error void cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer[]

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How do I implement the InsertionSort for an array? Could you please tell me what the correct code would've been in this case:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static void insertionSort(Integer [] a ){
        for(Integer i = 1; i>= a.length ; i++){
            Integer toInsert = a[i];
            Integer j = i;
            while (j>0 && a[j-1]> toInsert){
                a [j] = a [j-1]; // a[j-1] wird eine Stelle nach rechts geschoben
                j--;
            }
            a [j] = toInsert;
        }
    }
    public static void main (String []args){
        Integer a1[] = new Integer[8];
        for(Integer i=0; i< a1.length;i++){
            a1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Zahl:"));
        }
        Integer a2[] = insertionSort(a1);
        for(Integer i=0; i<a2.length; i++){
            System.out.println(a2[i]+", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer a2[] = insertionSort(a1);` makes no sense, since your `insertionSort` does not *return* anything. It is a void.

Comment: Full error-output maybe a line number etc would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct one:

```
public class InsertionSort
{
   public static void insertionSort(Integer[] a)
   {
      for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
      {
         Integer toInsert = a[i];
         int j = i;
         while (j > 0 && a[j - 1] > toInsert)
         {
            a[j] = a[j - 1]; // a[j-1] wird eine Stelle nach rechts geschoben
            j--;
         }
         a[j] = toInsert;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Integer a1[] = new Integer[8];
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
         a1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Zahl:"));
      }
      insertionSort(a1);
      for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println(a1[i] + ", ");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Manoj! Do you know why the unsorted array is printed running that code?

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you explain that?